# How to reindex malformed columns retrived from pandas read_html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I am retrieving some content from a website which has several tables with the same number of columns, with pandas [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-html). When I read a single link that actually has several tables with the same number of columns, pandas effectively read all the tables as one (something like a flat/normalized table). However, I am interested in do the same for a list of links from a website (i.e. a single flat table for several links), so I tried the following:

In:

```
import multiprocessing
def process(url):
    df_url = pd.read_html(url)
    df = pd.concat(df_url, ignore_index=False) 
    return df_url

links = ['link1.com','link2.com','link3.com',...,'linkN.com']

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
df = pool.map(process, links)
df
```

Nevertheless, I guess I am not specifiying corecctly to `read_html()` which are the columns, so I am getting this malformed list of lists:

Out:

```
[[                Form     Disponibility  \
  0  290090 01780-500-01)  Unavailable - no product available for release.   

                             Relation  \

     Relation drawbacks  
  0                  NaN                        Removed 
  1                  NaN                        Removed ],
 [                                        Form  \

                                   Relation  \
  0  American Regent is currently releasing the 0.4...   
  1  American Regent is currently releasing the 1mg...   

     drawbacks  
  0  Demand increase for the drug  
  1                         Removed ,
                                          Form  \
  0  0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Luer-Jet Prefilled Syringe (N...   

    Disponibility  Relation  \
  0                            Product available                  NaN   
  2                        Removed 
  3                        Removed ]]
```

So my question **which parameter should I move in order to get a flat pandas dataframe from the above nested list**?. I tried to `header=0`, `index_col=0`, `match='"columns"'`, none of them worked or do I need to do the flatting when I create the pandas dataframe with `pd.Dataframe()`?. My main objective is to have a pandas dataframe like with this columns:

```
form, Disponibility, Relation, drawbacks
1 
2
...
n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

first you want to return concatenated DF, instead of list of DFs (as `read_html` returns a **list** of DFs):

```
def process(url):
    return pd.concat(pd.read_html(url), ignore_index=False)
```

and then concatenate them for all URLs:

```
df = pd.concat(pool.map(process, links), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In `----> 4 df = pd.concat(pool.map(process, links), ignore_index=True)`. I got: `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`. Any idea of why this is happening and what to do?.

Comment: @tumbleweed, what does `pool.map(process, links)` return? Is it a list of DFs or something different?

Comment: Thanks again Max, hold on I re-run it and is taking a while.

Comment: Wow!... it actually worked!, pandas is a very powerful tool.

Comment: @tumbleweed, it is indeed a very powerful tool! :-) Glad i could help...

Comment: Thank you very much @MaxU... this was actually a hard question... If it's ok if I give you a 50 bounty?.... If yes, I will unaccept the question and wait until I can put a bounty.

Comment: @tumbleweed, no, don't do this, keep your reputation points for more difficult questions ;-)